# Reboot/Power Off Android Emulator

Tags: android, fonts, android-emulator

I installed new fonts on my Android emulator.  The instructions say I have to reboot my device.  I tried using the "Power Off" button but it just displays "Shutting Down" and does nothing.  Even when I go to the adb shell and run "reboot" it hangs.

Any ideas how to restart the emulator so that the new settings appear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

Here is a quick way to restart/ reboot emulator:

1. Go to "Android Virtual Device Manager"
2. Click on the dropdown menu in "Action" column
3. Select "Cold Boot Now" option in menu

Now emulator will restart/reboot and power will ON.

Comment: You may have to choose "stop" from that menu first.

Answer (score 16):

Basically you are not supposed to shut it down... Just close the window.

This is what's written in the documentation

```
To stop an emulator instance, just close the emulator's window.
```

**Reference:**

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#starting

Answer (score 12):

It occurs sometimes when emulator snapshots are enabled (I think your problem is not related to fonts installation).

Try this command to start your virtual device without snapshot:

```
emulator -no-snapshot-load -avd YOUR_AVD
```

Answer (score 10):

Hmmm... another way is wiping out current emulator and re-start from initial state..

1. just close your emulator window
2. launch AVD Manager from eclipse
3. press Start button
4. check "Wipe user data"
5. click "Launch" and you will get clean and initial state of emulator

Comment: Wipe user data did not work for my case. I deleted and recreated a new AVD. I used a different name just in case. (in eclipse)

Comment: But wiping user data would ALSO remove the new fonts he installed. Therefore not a solution to the question. OTOH, it sounds like he has got an emulator that is "stuck" in some bad state. So he might need to do what you suggest, then start over with font installation.

Answer (score 5):

Choose the emulator in "Android sdk and avd manager", edit it, and remove the tick from "snapshot". Then the emulator will restart every time you run it.

Answer (score 5):

In the AVD Manager, you can click on "Cold Boot Now" under "Actions" column of the device you want to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

maybe see my answer at [Ambitious attempt at running android app on multiple emulators - can't stop emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748855/ambitious-attempt-at-running-android-app-on-multiple-emulators-cant-stop-emul/42903710#42903710)

Answer (score -2):

You can just close the emulator window.

Comment: yeah, can't you just kill it and start it again?

Comment: yeah i can do that, but i don't think it actually shuts down the phone.  I don't see the new fonts when I start up the emulator again.

Comment: Could it be a problem with the installation? Can you somehow verify it has been installed correctly?

Comment: it's installed correctly...tried with android version 1.6, 2.0, 2.1, still no luck...has anyone been able to "power off" the emulator or is this a bug?